# Convert CSV to XLSX in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to know , how can I convert a csv file to XLSX. I want to set a  Update patch report for a notification , but the file is in csv format.

Somebody has a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no service in AWS supporting file transcoding however you can use a simple lambda function to this transcoding with any language you prefer.

You can use an S3 bucket to trigger the lambda function whenever your CSV is uploaded to S3.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Does not have a service for this type of conversion. The solution is you write a Lambda function that is able to work with Excel documents and CSV files in a supported programming language. Here is a similar use case that has been implemented in Java.

[image]

In this example, population data located in a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet and stored in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket is retrieved, transformed to another format, and stored in an Amazon DynamoDB table named Country.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_etl_workflow